# rss sibling count with jquery

Tags: jquery, rss, siblings

I'm trying to get certain items from an rss feed with this script:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var url = '/rss';
    var $list = $('#recent-posts');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data) {                
            var $items = $(data).find('item');
            $items.each( function() {
                var $item = $(this);
                var link = $item.children('link').text();
                var title = $item.children('title').text();
                if (link && title) {
                    $list.append($('<li><a href="' + link + '">' + title + '</a></li>'));
                }
            });
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

What i can't figure out, is how to get the nth items of which have many siblings with the same name.

for example:

```
<item>
 <category>content</category>
 <category>content2</category>
 <category>content3</category>
</item>
```

`var tags = $item.children('category')[1];` displays `<category>content2</category>`
but how can i display only the content of that specific 'category'?

Thanks!

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking or what you want to display. Show expected results and provide better explanation. Don't you just want to iterate all those `<category>`?

Comment: in the last two lines i tried to ask the question - maybe its not clear enough. var tags = $item.children('category')[1];    displays  <category>content2</category>  but i need 'content2' specifically

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if it was clear

Comment: edited the comment above :)

Comment: try `$item.children('category')[1].text()`

Comment: yes, thats the problem. console says "Uncaught TypeError: $item.children(...)[1].text is not a function"

Comment: oops ... use `$item.children('category').eq(1).text()`. Or if you loop over the elements in `each` use `$(this).text()`

Comment: oh my...Thank you. I post it as an answer, just for the record

Answer (score 0):

use `$item.children('category').eq(1).text()`. Or if you loop over the elements in each use `$(this).text()` – charlietfl